# Two different version of jars on seperate threads in a single JVM

Tags: java, classloader

Is it possible to run two jars of different version, but runs on different thread on a single JVM. If so, please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: No, the classfile which is loaded at last will be the one that will be executed. that's how the classes are loaded in JVM

Comment: You can have that, but you'll need to get deeply involved with classloader hierarchy and custom classloaders.

Comment: You don't need a separate thread, you just need two ClassLoaders.  Or you can use a tool like `jarjar` to give the different versions, different package names. However, it might be much simpler to have two JVMs and have only one JAR version per JVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, that is very well possible - when using multiple [ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) instances. Meaning: when each of your thread is using its own special ClassLoader, those threads could be working with "different" versions of the "same" jar file.

But a word of warning: this is really an advanced topic that you don't want to get into lighthearted! If you are really interested in going there, you can find some further reading [here](http://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader).